# bold html string from code behind asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want the message to be in bold when it is presented in the alert box . I am using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript to for creating javascript alert box

I tried using b tag in the string , but its not working , asp.net does not translate it into  its html equivalent

Answer (score 2):

Javascript `alert()` box cannot be formatted.

If you wish to format the text you should use a [custom modal popup](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/FCreL/*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change that. The alert box and confirm box.. it is as per the browser perspective. you cannot change that. Yeah you can create your own dialog box..

If you wish to create your own dialog box then you may find this interesting
[jQuery UI Dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the text style in the default javascript alert box.

If you want to style an alert you would be best served by creating a 'pop up' div, in which you can put in HTML content. Something like [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) may be better suited to your needsd.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the text style in the standart alert.
You might look through these links about creating DHTML popups, though I think that is far too much work to just bolden the text on an alert.

http://www.openwebware.com/products/openpopups/

http://www.subimage.com/dhtml/subModal/

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/dhtmlwindow/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

The `alert()` dialog is not rendered in `HTML`. so better option to go with custom alert box or confirm box.

Here you go: [Modal Dialog Box](http://www.javascriptplugins.com/javascript/plugin/modal-dialog-box/)

Comment: You are wrong it display the message like <b>Hello World</b>... not BOLD letters...

Comment: Is it possible? r u confirmed?

Comment: it returns <b>Hello world</b>?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. But you can use custom Alert and Confirm boxes.

You can read about some User Interface libraries here:

http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/17/15-javascript-web-ui-libraries-frameworks-and-libraries/

Most common libraries are:

- http://jqueryui.com/
- http://mootools.net/
- http://www.prototype-ui.com/
- http://script.aculo.us/
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/